# Powershell how to allow blocked content in internet explorer

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

[image]

Have any idea using powershell how to enable and disable "Alloww active content to run in files on my computer" in IE properties..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
This worked for me !

When the HTML page is loaded from local machine (local file path), the ActiveX control can be blocked by the Local Machine Lockdown feature.  You should be able to workaround it by adding a mark-of-web
 (<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->) at the beginning of your HTML page.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same from registry Key. First create the registry key `iexplore.exe` (Dword)
in the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN`

If you set the value to 1 the 'Allow active content to run in files on my computer' will be unchecked.

If you set the value to 0 the 'Allow active content to run in files on my computer' will be checked.